# Representing functions as power series: Homework questions

Tags: calculus

[image: The question]

Completed all my homework exept for this problem. Our teacher likes to give us a problem at the end that is for a future lesson. That is this question above. So it is kind of tricky...

I don't have any written solution so far. I believe there is something to do with the power rule in the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

njguliyev’s answer points you at the slick way, which I recommend, but the problem can be done by brute force as well. If you differentiate $f$ a few times, it’s not too hard to pick up the pattern:

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\frac3{4-x}=3(4-x)^{-1}\\
f\,'(x)&=1\cdot3(4-x)^{-2}\\
f''(x)&=2\cdot1\cdot3(4-x)^{-3}\\
f'''(x)&=3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot3(4-x)^{-4}\\
&\;\vdots\\
f^{(n)}(x)&=n!\cdot3(4-x)^{-n-1}=\frac{3n!}{(4-x)^{n+1}}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now just substitute into the usual formula for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series expansion about $1$.

Answer (score 4):

*Hints:*
$$\dfrac{3}{4-x} = \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{x-1}{3}}$$
and
$$\dfrac1{1-y} = 1+y+y^2+\ldots.$$